# pip unable to find newest package version

Tags: python-3.x, pypi

I'm having an issue installing a new package version using `pip`.

Im working on [my package](https://pypi.org/project/the-spymaster-util/), and recently uploaded a new version (`==1.9.0`), the same way I always do using `twine upload`. The upload was successful. When trying to install the new version, I get the following error:

```
>>> pip install the-spymaster-util==1.9.0
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement the-spymaster-util==1.9.0 (from versions: 0.1.1, 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0, 1.5.0, 1.6.0, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.8.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for the-spymaster-util==1.9.0
```

as if version `1.9.0` doen't exist. The wierd thing is that it [does exist in pypi index](https://pypi.org/project/the-spymaster-util/1.9.0/), just that for some reason my local index refuses to update according to it. Also, the newest version (`==1.9.1` as im writing this question), does not appear as the "lastest" version - but `1.8.0` does. Usually the index updates within a few seconds after the upload is completed.

Am I missing something?

Comment: you need to wait a bit until the upload propagates (some fastly cdn caching thing as far as i know) and sometimes running pip again fixes it.

Comment: Im aware of it - as I wrote - this usually takes a few seconds to update (im also familiar with running pip install twice). Right now im more then 1 hour after my upload (and countelss desperate pip installs), still no change.

Comment: I face the same issue with my package, so maybe this might be some more general pypi issue?

Comment: Now (~9 hours later) it seems the index has updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is probably some caching delay in pypi as mentiond in the comment by @Bijany, I did find my way around this (not production-ready, but good enough to keep local developemnt going):

1. Open your specific package version page in pypi (e.g. https://pypi.org/project/package_name/package_version)
2. Click on `Download Files`.
3. Copy the `Source Distribution` file URL (the `.tar.gz` file).
4. In the command line, run: `pip install <file_url>`.

Edit: it appears that there in an ongoing related incident: https://status.python.org/incidents/l16ylxktn4r9