# It's not possible to install the newest version of my package

Tags: pip

I have some troubles with upgrading my package

```
pip install --upgrade pgwidget
```

The point is, it has available version 0.4.1 (https://pypi.org/project/pgwidget/0.4.1/) already but when I upgrade or reinstall I always get 0.3.14 instead of 0.4.1

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Comment: A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72765607/11082165) was asked an hour ago.

Comment: Thanks, maybe this is some more general issue with pypi index